# jQuery Else / If Prevent Inheriting Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I am wondering how I prevent elements from retaining the same inline styles in my else / if breakpoints.

What I am doing is trying to change styling based on window width. Very much the same approach as CSS media queries, except I need to increment a numeric value, which is something I cannot do with CSS, hence the jQuery.

When I get to my final else if - where I apply an opacity to the first 5 articles - if I resize my browser back down to the less than 720px, those articles retain the opacity, which I do not want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();
        if (windowSize >= 1 && windowSize <= 479) {
            var posTop = 0;
            $('#main article').each(function() {
                $(this).css('top', posTop + 'px');
                posTop += 160;
            });
        } else if (windowSize >= 480 && windowSize <= 719) {
            var posTop = 0;
            $('#main article').each(function() {
                $(this).css('top', posTop + 'px');
                posTop += 240;
            });
        } else if (windowSize >= 720 && windowSize <= 959) {
            $('#main article').slice(0, 5).each(function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', 0.4);
            });
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});​
```

Comment: You need to set the opacity in all branches of the if..else logic.

Comment: are you aware of the fact that you can use expressions inside you css? Normally not a big fan of it, but in this case it is pure styling you are doing and it would keep all your styling together. something like this http://www.richnetapps.com/using_javascript_expressions_in_css/

Comment: Wow I had no idea about css expressions... not sure if I want to take this route but I'm definitely going to experiment with it. Thanks for the tip dude.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('#main article').css('opacity', 1);` at the begining of `checkWidth` function. By the way, you should rename this function, because what it does is not how it sounds. And there is no need in `posTop` variable and last `each` loop. My variant with some refactoring:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeStylesDependsOnWidth() {
        $('#main article').css('opacity', 1);

        var windowSize = $(window).width();

        if (windowSize >= 1 && windowSize <= 479) {
            $('#main article').each(function(i) {
                $(this).css('top', i * 160 + 'px');
            });
        } else if (windowSize >= 480 && windowSize <= 719) {
            $('#main article').each(function(i) {
                $(this).css('top', i * 240 + 'px');
            });
        } else if (windowSize >= 720 && windowSize <= 959) {
            $('#main article').slice(0, 5).css('opacity', 0.4);
        }
    }

    changeStylesDependsOnWidth();
    $(window).resize(changeStylesDependsOnWidth);
});​
```

Comment: He gets notified of answers.  You don't need to "bump" :p

Comment: Hey I'm going to test this code in a second, just have to finish up some work, sorry for the delay but I really appreciate the help! I will let you know how this works out.

Comment: I meant to revisit this... your code did not work for me unfortunately, but I have not given up. I will return to this as soon as possible.